# nexmo sms api is not working

Tags: php, laravel, api, sms

```
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query(
              [
                'api_key' =>  'xxxxx',
                'api_secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
                'to' => $mobile,
                'from' => 'ABC',
                'text' => $message,
              ]
              ); 
              $ch = curl_init($url);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
              $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

This api is not working and not showing any error. I used only this code to send sms anything other is also needed?
I used api_key and secret correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> assuming that you checked values of $mobile and $message **before** using and that they're ok

EDIT: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page and check updated code

EDIT 2:

> It works **only** with your registered phone number with trial API **and** with registered number as dest
>   This is meant to avoid spam

You need to put `$mobile` and `$message` like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
print_r($_POST);
echo"[ num: $mobile / mess: $message]";

$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query(

[
  'api_key' =>  'xxxxx',
  'api_secret' => 'xxxxxx',
  'to' => ''.$mobile.'', /* dest phone number */
  'from' => '33012345678', /* my own phone number */
  'text' => ''.$message.'' /* my message */
]
);
```

[NEXMO API how-to](https://docs.nexmo.com/messaging/sms-api)

Comment: `"https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=xxxxx&api_secret=xxx&to=91xxxx871472&from=ABC&text=Hi.+Your+OTP+is%3A+3A55NP"`

Comment: with your own credentials ? add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page and see if PHP say something (FYI: runs smoothly on my side...)

Comment: I'm using trial api so is it compulsory to put in `from` = `valid_no`??

Comment: It works **only** with your registered number with trial API **and** with registered number as dest (see updated answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143621/discussion-between-giridhari-lal-and-oldpadawan).